# Metadata document shows a POST based sample for a GET based DTO

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have the following DTO where the URI should be like `api/logs?verbose=`, where `verbose` can be `true` or `false`.

```cs
[Route("/api/logs", "GET")]
public class GetLogs
{
    public bool Verbose { get; set; }
}
```

My service is:

```cs
public object Get(GetLogs getLogs)
{
    //For brevity
    return getLogs;
}
```

I see that the sample that generated in metadata document mentions POST instead of GET, which I explicitly set.

```
POST /json/oneway/GetLogs HTTP/1.1 
Host: localhost 
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: length

{"Verbose":false}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, that is just a sample. Don't take the "POST /json/oneway/GetLogs HTTP/1.1" literally. You should be using the actual Route endpoints shown earlier in the same page, which would likely be:

The following routes are available for this service:

GET /api/logs

In my ServiceStack projects, they are all the same way - the sample is POST, even if the available routes are only: GET, OPTIONS

I did some searching, and this appears to be hardcoded in the class: [ServiceStack.Metadata.OperationControl](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/5d09d439cd1a13712411552e2b3ede5a71af2ee5/src/ServiceStack/Metadata/OperationControl.cs)

So you could accept you "can't do it" with the current release. Or figure out how to override or patch OperationControl template rendering.